# Python desktopcouch storing dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nosql, couchdb, record

First of all, one strange behavior of desktopcouch.records.server.CouchDatabase:

`db.get_record(id)` returns:

```
<desktopcouch.records.RecordDict object at 0x9198f2c>
```

`db.get_records('mytype', True)` returns array of:

```
<Row id='5rMlni6ZYudp5gvSADve1Y', key='mytype', ...>
```

Where db is `CouchDatabase('mydb', create=True)`

Why this difference?

This leads to returning my dict which is saved under record as empty dict {}, as `<desktopcouch.records.RecordDict object at 0x9198f2c>` in first and as {} in second case.

That makes some problems when fetching it with db.get_record(id) and updating with db.update_fields(id, record). It throws ''Document' object has no attribute 'read''

Where am I doing it wrong?

**EDIT:**

I posted a bug to Desktop CouchDB with explanation and snippet to reproduce this behaviour https://bugs.launchpad.net/desktopcouch/+bug/905913

Comment: the `RecordDict` seems to be a dict too, could you try it?

Comment: @FelixYan Thanks for the answer. To try what? It fails to save my record when it has RecordDict attribute. Everything works with regular {}. BTW is there some API doc for desktopcpuch? I found only http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktopcouch/Documentation/ which looks really poor.

Comment: Don't know much about it, but you can still try to `dict()` it, if it's really a dict(which is showed in its name), you will get a python dict then.

Comment: I have tried that, but got same error, now I discovered what is the reason, and I am even more confused. Look at the piece of code and what it prints https://gist.github.com/1492994 (tmp is desktopcouch.records.Record), that is one of the reasons. I expected last print to be {}, not <desktopcouch.records.RecordDict object at 0xa1d0f0c>.

Answer (score 1):

By looking into its code, I find that it's not a normal dict, but you can get it to be dict anyway.

Try this:

```
print dict(tmp['logs'].items())
```

**EDIT:**

As for the confusion, when you set the converted dict back to a `Record` object, it runs

```
super(Record, self).__setitem__(key, item)
```

So according to its inherit, it runs the `RecordDict` object's `__setitem__` method, which runs:

```
super(RecordDict, self).__setitem__(key, item)
```

So again, see the `RecordData` object's `__setitem__` method, it is:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    if isinstance(item, (list, tuple, dict)):
        item = record_factory(item)
    if hasattr(item, '_data'):
        item = item._data
    self._data[key] = item
```

So it uses `record_factory` to convert the dict you parsed in to `RecordDict` again. So you see those results :)

Comment: Thx, but this gives same result https://gist.github.com/1492994. I can convert it, with or without calling items() method. But can't assign it back to my Record. I'm afraid I'm missing sth and going wrong path. I should find out why db.get_record() and db.get_records() return different result (data types).

Comment: A `print dict(tmp['logs'].items())` returning empty dict should mean that the RecordDict is really empty, recording to its code. You can also try to use other method like `.keys()` to the RecordDict object too, they should return empty list too.

Comment: And about assigning back, you may use `record_factory` module level method, which converts dict, list or tuple to `RecordDict` or `MergeableList`.

Comment: But why value is not assisgned to a variable (line #3)?!? :)

Comment: No, it's desktopcouch.records.Record

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I still don't know why db.get_record and db.get_records returning different results. And how to update this dict. I posted a bug to Desktop CouchDB with explanation and snippet to reproduce this behaviour https://bugs.launchpad.net/desktopcouch/+bug/905913

Comment: That's because `get_records()` is a customized function to get records from a view named `C{get_records_and_type}`, you can find its source code in records/server_base.py, and `get_record` is just as simply to get a record from back end storage.

Comment: Thanks. All in all, I'm still looking for a way to update desktopcouch.records.RecordDict which is inside my Record. I didn't run into any problems as long as it was a list. But since it wasted a lot of time iterating list to find desired item, I switched to dict in order to access items dirrectly with simple dict[key].

Comment: You can always update it directly just acting as it's a normal python dict :) It has most of the features that a normal dict has, too.

Comment: I whish, but it throws ''Document' object has no attribute 'read'' on update, that's why I started this discussion. Please check https://gist.github.com/1496379